# import router from express.Router()

Tags: node.js, express

I have this on top of my **index.js**

```
import express from 'express'
import favicon from 'serve-favicon'
import router from express.Router()
```

I kept getting

```
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `babel-node ./index.js`
/Users/bheng/Desktop/express-app/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:590
      throw err;
      ^

SyntaxError: /Users/bheng/Desktop/express-app/index.js: Unexpected token (3:19)
  1 | import express from 'express'
  2 | import favicon from 'serve-favicon'
> 3 | import router from express.Router()
    |                    ^
```

What is the correct syntax for that ? What did I do wrong ?

[image]

Comment: You cannot import from a function invocation. Do you mean `const router = express.Router();`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You already imported express, so to access the `Router` you don't need to import anymore.

```
const router = express.Router();
```

Comment: Ahh.. ok. sorry. new to node.